# Can I publish a NuGet package without using Nuget.exe?

Tags: nuget

This may sound like an odd requirement, but I need to be able to push a NuGet package without using NuGet.exe.

I have a task to complete using a build agent that's normally used for docker builds; it's a Linux VM and it has almost nothing installed on it other than docker. I can create the package manually with a shell script, but I don't know how to push it to our nuget feed from a machine that doesn't have .NET installed or NuGet.exe.

Can I simply curl the file up to the feed, somehow? What endpoint to I need? How are the credentials supplied? What's the format of the HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use `curl` for that. Lets say, you are publishing your package with `dotnet nuget` like this:

```
dotnet nuget push C:\Path\To\Package.1.2.3.nupkg --api-key 1234567890abcd --source http://localhost:44387/nuget
```

`curl` equivalent will be:

```
curl --verbose -k -X PUT http://localhost:44387/nuget -H "X-NuGet-ApiKey: 1234567890abcd" -F "data=@C:\Path\To\Package.1.2.3.nupkg"
```